# DRBD config to automatically resolve any split brain

Tags: drbd

I'm running 2 node cluster with DRBD (active/passive) managed by the drbd systemd service and a small script that mounts volumes whenever a resource becomes primary.

I want to configure the DRBD in such a way that it will always resolve any split brain and always have at least one node which is primary and able to serve in any case as long as not both machines are down.

I tried the following configuration (where `pri-lost-after-sb` is  `"reboot"`)

```
after-sb-0pri discard-younger-primary;
after-sb-1pri discard-secondary;
after-sb-2pri call-pri-lost-after-sb;
```

and `on-suspended-primary-outdated force-secondary` and some other combinations.

But I always find a scenario where the cluster gets into bad states and doesn't recover from a split brain. Usually I'm getting `StandAlone` on the nodes and `force-io-failures` on the secondary (so after another fail of the primary, this secondary will not work even if connected).

Is there anything else I can do to improve the robustness of this setup considering I highly prioritize service uptime and not the avoidance of data loss?

Answer (score 5):

Back in the days, I have tried multiple times to setup a similar cluster. That was until I understood that DRBD is broken by design and goes by "split brain" as its second name. In DRBD9, things got a bit better (only in comparison with 8.xx which was a nightmare) but it still can't be used in production. I see only one solution - save your time and migrate to something more reliable. For example, Ceph.

Comment: Ceph won't do 2 nodes, even with a witness. You need 3 nodes minimum, while 4 nodes is recommended for production cluster. Except that I absolutely agree, ditching DRBD in favor of Ceph seems to be a way more productive time spending than trying to fix broken DRBD setup.